# Are there more than one families of flow networks with non unique minimum cuts?

Tags: algorithm

I'm wondering if the only way to construct a flow network with several minimum cuts is to include at least 2 consecutive edges with the same capacity, such that any one of them will be in the minimum cut edge set.

It's clear that the simplest kind of such a network is a path with all edges of the same capacity, so in that case any one of |E| edges can be the edge separating S from T.

Is this the only way to construct such networks? If so, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is true:

Consider this network:

```
A->B capacity 4
B->C capacity 2
A->C capacity 1
C->D capacity 3
```

We can either have a cut (A,B,C)/(D)  or (A,B)/(C,D) both with cut of 3.

[image]

Comment: Oh yea, that's true, so it's all about a vertex that takes in x and pushes out x, such that the edges that go in or go out can be in a minimum cut, thanks.

Comment: You could even have C->X having capacity 5, and X->D having capacity 3, so the min-cuts are not even adjacent.

Comment: that's true, my brain is still bad an coming up with network flow ideas

Comment: but in this question they explained that min cut is unique? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673711/determining-the-uniqueness-of-a-min-cut

Comment: @user9355495 I believe in the other question they explain a method to determine whether a min cut is unique or not.

Comment: I do not understand the difference between these two questions properly can you kindly elaborate a little?

Comment: This question is asking for an example of a graph with a min-cut that is not unique.  The other question is asking for an algorithm that allows a test of whether the min-cut for a graph is unique or not.